# Specify different instant type for nodes in kubernetes with kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I am creating a kubernetes cluster in `AWS` with `kops`.

I understand that I can change the nodes' instance type using following command.

`kops edit ig nodes --name ${NAME}`

It will open this file and I can edit config

```
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-12-07T11:09:37Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: <cluster-name>.k8s.local
  name: nodes
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.10-debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-ebs-2018-08-17
  machineType: t2.large
  maxSize: 5
  minSize: 3
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: nodes
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - eu-west-2a
  - eu-west-2b
  - eu-west-2c
```

What if I want to create one node with `xlarge` type and two another in `large` type. I don't see any option to set these type of value.

The reason for this is, in my current infrastructure, the DB is residing in a 2xlarge instance and all other small componentes are in large instance. So I want nodes to be as big a possible. 
Another solution is instead of three I create only two 2xlarge nodes and let kuberentes manage the deployment.

Comment: you can create new instance group. Is it okay with you? I can provide an example.
Or you can edit existing instanceGroup also. In that case, all node will be in new InstanceType.

Comment: That looks good. All the groups will be in the same cluster, right?

Comment: yes. All groups will be in same cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new instance group
Then, preview and last apply the changes.

```
 Create: $ kops create ig <new-instace-group-name> --state <your-s3-bucket-name>    
 Preview: $ kops update cluster --name <cluster-name> --state="<your-s3-bucket-name>"    
 Apply: $ kops update cluster --name <cluster-name> --state="<your-s3-bucket-name>" --yes
```